# Radio Button Group display vertically

Tags: gwt

I am using the `GWT` to build the radio button , but when i display it shows one after another (in row).

Is there any way to stack the radio buttons in the group vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the Panel you are adding it to. If you want things to line up vertically without any hassle, add each radio button to a `VerticalPanel`.

The reason it lines up is because GWT generates `RadioButtons` as HTML `<span>` elements, which by default has the CSS `display` set to `inline`.

If you prefer not to use a VerticalPanel, you can make `RadioButtons` have `display:block;`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to wrap each RadioButton in a SimplePanel.

Another way is to set their `display` css attribute to `block`.

Answer (score 0):

`GWT` `RadioButton` has a default provided `CSS` class for styling the `RadioButton` `gwt-RadioButton`

Example :

```
.gwt-RadioButton
{
    display : block;
}
```